# How to Change Output directory Of a Type Script File in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, typescript1.4, typescript1.5

I feel ridiculous for asking this because it seems like it should be so simple, however I have been unable to discover an answer to this question.

I am having my Script folder in c drive and my project is in d drive each time when i made any changes in my (Type Script) application i need to do the same changes in my C drive folder as well, which is very problematic.I need a solution so that i can refer my c drive directory in my visual studio and when i compile my application it will automatically make changes into my c drive script folder not the one which is in my application...

For Example :-
My Application with my Type Scripts is in D:\Webapp\Scripts
And I want to get all compile file at C:\Scripts\

or

Is there any option to add the js files into my solutions from my C Drive Only without storing them in my application folder.So that i can access it from my C drive and Compile them there only.

I have done with

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*.ts" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot; @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot; --outDir myoutputdirectory', ' ')" />
 </Target>
```

and By this too:-

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <TypeScriptOutDir>my/dir</TypeScriptOutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <TypeScriptOutDir>my/dir</TypeScriptOutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But Problem Remains Same
Any Help Will be Great full.....

Comment: Would a Directory Junction work (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) i.e. create a junction under your project directory that points to your scripts folder on C? Because the junction is in your project folder you could then use the 'Show all Files' and 'Include in Project' options in the navigation tree of Visual Studio.

Comment: @ScheuNZ is it possible to change my output folder...